# ASP.Net MVC4->How to setup this routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was wondering how to setup routing in my MVC4 application where I can have a controller named TMZ and have it handle all of these routes:

```
/TMZ/About
/TMZ/Webinars
/TMZ/News
/TMZ/Conferment
/TMZ/CustomerCare
/TMZ/Marketing/Emails
/TMZ/Marketing/Brochures
/TMZ/Marketing/Print
/TMZ/Marketing/Press
/TMZ/Marketing/Presentations
/TMZ/Marketing/Graphics
/TMZ/Marketing/OCSRY
/TMZ/Marketing/Resources
/TMZ/Marketing/DesignStandards
/TMZ/Marketing/Videos
/TMZ/Marketing/PromoKits
/TMZ/Faculty/Forms
/TMZ/Faculty/Reports
/TMZ/CE/Guides
/TMZ/CE/Reports
/TMZ/Academy/Papers
/TMZ/Academy/Books
/TMZ/Academy/Promotions
/TMZ/ManualOfOperations
```

**Showing Code:**

Here is my RouteConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace LicenseeArchive
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("TMZ",
                   "TMZ/{action}/{subaction}/{id}",
                   new { controller = "TMZ", action = "Index", subaction = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                   null,
                   new[] { "LicenseeArchive.Web.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute("Default",
                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                   null,
                   new[] { "LicenseeArchive.Web.Controllers" });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace LicenseeArchive
{

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my TMZController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LicenseeArchive.Controllers
{
    public class TMZController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /TMZ/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Marketing(string subaction)
        {
            string _view = "Index";
            switch (subaction)
            {
                case "Brochures":
                    _view = "Marketing/Brochures";
                    break;                
            }
            return View(_view);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my View folder structure:

```
Views
    Account
        Login.cshtml
        Manage.cshtml
        Register.cshtml
    Home
        About.cshtml
        Contact.cshtml
        Index.cshtml
    Shared
        _Footer.cshtml
        _Head.cshtml
        _HeaderBlock.cshtml
        _Layout.cshtml
        _LeftAside.cshtml
        _LoginPartial.cshtml
        _TopNav.cshtml
        Error.cshtml
    TMZ
        Academy
            Books.cshtml
            Papers.cshtml
            Promotions.cshtml
        CE
            Guides.cshtml
            Reports.cshtml
        Faculty
            Forms.cshtml
            Reports.cshtml
        Marketing
            Emails.cshtml
            Brochures.cshtml
            Print.cshtml
            Press.cshtml
            Presentations.cshtml
            Graphics.cshtml
            OCSRY.cshtml
            Resources.cshtml
            DesignStandards.cshtml
            Videos.cshtml
            PromoKits.cshtml
        About.cshtml
        Conferment.cshtml
        CustomerCare.cshtml
        News.cshtml
        ManualOfOperations.cshtml
        Webinars.cshtml
    _ViewStart.cshtml
    Web.Config
```

Comment: TMZ should be the root of your site (a static part of the route). The Controller would be the next portion of the URL. The third part would be the individual Actions.

Comment: But I'm also going to have Home and Account Controllers as well as a Mail controller. I am reading up now on Areas, I think this may be the solution.

Comment: You should add your route before the default route. Here you're adding it after registering all routs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be modify the "default" route in `Global.asax.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{subaction}/{id}",
       new {subaction= UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

This would mean you could use the same url format in other Controllers as well. Your TMZController would look something like:

```
public class TMZController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Marketing(string subaction)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Because the subaction/id are both optional you can construct 2, 3 or 4-part urls and just pickup the extra parameters in your actions, then handle them as required within the body of the methods.

Comment: +1 Good idea. This answer is better than mine. I should admit that :)

Comment: Thanks :) To be fair your answer probably works better if you specifically want that url format to ONLY go to one controller, and will never want this format elsewhere. It really depends whether @MB34 wants a generic approach that works everywhere or a one-off to handle one special case...

Comment: Was unaware of the `{subaction}` "verb". Not ever going to need the `{id}`, however. I am about half way done with doing it using a TMZ Area.

Comment: All of the url/route parameters are configurable - you could add one called {ungabunga} if you wanted :) {Controller}, {action} and {id} are simply the default ones, the wiring up to fire the relevant Controller/Action occurs in the MvcRouteHandler/DefaultControllerFactory. You could take {id} out of the above and it would work fine.

Comment: Due to discussions with another developer here, I decided to not use Areas. Ok, look at my code above. If I use the URL `/Index`, it shows my `/Home/Index` view, 
if I use the URL `/TMZ/Index` or `/TMZ/Marketing/Brochure` it shows the 
`/Home/Index` view, not the Index view in the `/Views/TMZ` folder
or the Brochure view defined in the `/Views/TMZ/Marketing` folder.

Comment: Looking at your updated code, the problem appears to be that in your Global.asax.cs you are calling `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` which contains the `Default` route, and because this is being added BEFORE your `TMZDefault` route it will handle any matching incoming Url's first. I suggest moving the `TMZDefault` route into the your RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes() method and removing the `Default` route registration as this is not required. This will cause the `TMZDefault` route to handle your url and it should behave as expected.

Comment: After changing to the code posted above, it is now working. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

```
routes.MapRoute("TMZ",
       "TMZ/{action}/{id}",
       new {controller = "TMZ", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
       null,
       new[] {"YourNamespace.Web.Controllers"});

routes.MapRoute("Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
       null,
       new[] {"YourNamespace.Web.Controllers"});
```

In this case i assumed that you've a Controller named TMZ and in that controller you've set all other actions including Marketing, Academy, Faculty, CE

But here is two things important to consider

1. This route should be before the default route "as I put it here"
2. The Actions in the `TMZController` should have an string id parameter to handle the request. this id would be passed something like "Resources" for the Marketing action or "Books" for Academy Action.

Hope this was clear.

Comment: I did something like this using Areas, based on the Apress book "Pro ASP.Net MVC4" chapter 14 on Advance Routing Features.

Comment: How would I take the controller name out of the URL, though? My Controller is TMZHomeController and my routes have to be TMZ/TMZHome/Action where I'd like it to be /TMZ/Action

Comment: Event doing it this way, I get the same result as I noted in my last comment on Stephen's answer.

Comment: I wished I could accept both answers, but his was the best with the subaction. However, i did give you an upvote.